# How do I calculate impulse when an object collides with plane(fixed object)?

Tags: collision-resolution, physics-engine

I've been developing simple 3D impulse-based physics engine.
I calculate impulse as follows:
$$j_r = \frac{-1(1+e)v_r\cdot\hat n}
{m_1^{-1}+\bbox[yellow,5px,border:2px solid red]{m_2^{-1}}+(I_1^{-1}(r_1\times\hat n)\times r_1+
\bbox[yellow,5px,border:2px solid red]{I_2^{-1}(r_2\times \hat n)\times r_2)}\cdot \hat n}
$$
where:
  \$e\$ is restitution constant
  \$\hat n\$ is a contact normal
  \$v_r\$ is relative velocity of the contact point
  \$m\$ is mass of objects
  \$I\$ is moment of inertia tensor
  \$r\$ is a vector from center of mass to contact point

**Note:** I've been assigned value 0.0f to the boxed/highlighted terms in the expression when an object collides with plane.

Then update linear & angular velocity as below:
$$
\begin{align}
v'_1&=v_1-\frac{j_r}{m_1}\hat n \\
v'_2&=v_2+\frac{j_r}{m_2}\hat n
\end{align}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
\omega'_1&={\omega}_1-j_rI_1^{-1}(r_1\times\hat n) \\
\omega'_2&={\omega}_2+j_rI_2^{-1}(r_2\times\hat n)
\end{align}
$$

Those expressions are referenced from the [Wikipedia *collision response* entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_response#Impulse-based_contact_model).

It works well when two objects collide.
However, the box object rotates strangely and continuously glide around when it collides with plane as below:
[image: problem]

(red sphere is detected contact point)

I set contact normal as plane normal.
I assume that the expression has to be modified for the case of fixed object (ex. plane).
I've been assigned value 0.0f to the boxed/highlighted terms in the expression when an object collides with plane.
Is this approach right?
If it isn't, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This issue was caused by mismatch of coordinates system.
I've assumed that my rigid body class has saved angular velocity vector as  **world** coordinates
but it turns out that it was saved as **local** coordinates.
This mistake caused weird movement as above.

Comment: By the way, "the approach" which I've mentioned at question was correct.

Comment: You might want to come back and mark this answer as accepted :)